# Simulating "submodule" in single repo with branches?

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

Is there some way to simulate submodule-like behavior in single repo via branches ?

I'm asking because I have no option of getting a second  repo ;(

So I need to separate the code, templates and data and manage them on their own ... and merge them in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to mimic submodules. If we have to, one might say that the update of a submodule could be compared to the merge of a branch.

When you want the changes from "code", "template" and "data", you simply merge them into your mainline branch to get all the "submodules".